# Laravel General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have two models:

**Category**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title',10);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Product**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index('category_id');
        $table->string('title', 20);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

When I run `php artisan make:migrate` I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products`
>   add constraint `products_category_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to put a foreign key between a `signed` big integer and an `unsigned` big integer. Make them both unsigned....

Comment: your code is right. you haven't to have any error

Comment: no, it's impossibile because if i replace my freing with  $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories'); no problem in table user id is a bigIncrement

Answer (score 2):

Both the referencing and referenced columns *must* have the same datatype, as explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. *The size and sign of integer types must be the same*. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

You should either make both columns unsigned, or both signed. Unsigned seems more relevant for an incremented key:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id'); # changed to unsigned
        $table->string('title',10);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index('category_id');
        $table->string('title', 20);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```